# How to cleanly start logging multiple times by removing all handlers with "removeHandler(...)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

During development I use the python logging module. For example, after an unhandled exception I'd like to re-run the program and freshly initialize the logging. 
For some reason it seems that I'm unable to remove all handlers from the log instance. Even so it was never deleted.

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print('Existing handlers:')
print(log.handlers)

#Remove all handlers:
for handler in log.handlers: #get rid of existing old handlers
    print('removing handler %s'%handler)
    log.removeHandler(handler)

#excpecting "[]" for log.handlers
print('Existing handlers after removal:')
print(log.handlers)

fh1 = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter1 = logging.Formatter('fh1: %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh1.setFormatter(formatter1)

fh2 = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter2 = logging.Formatter('fh2: %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh2.setFormatter(formatter2)

log.addHandler(fh1)
log.addHandler(fh2)

log.error('Some logging occurs here')
```

On the first run in a fresh IPython console I get:

```
fh1: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
fh2: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
Existing handlers:
[]
Existing handlers after removal:
[]
```

This almost what I expected. The order of appearance bugs me a bit. Why does the log appear before the print output? It really gets strange when starting the program a second time:

```
fh2: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
fh1: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
fh2: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
Existing handlers:
[<StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>]
removing handler <StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>
Existing handlers after removal:
[<StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>]
```

It seems that the for loop, removing the handles, is executed just one time only. 
And than consequently I get 3 logging entries, which is not what I want. I expected for the second run:

```
Existing handlers:
[<StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>]
removing handler <StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>
removing handler <StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>
Existing handlers after removal:
[]
fh1: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
fh2: ERROR - Some logging occurs here
```

I seem to have missed some of the concept. 
+ Why does the for loop just run one time, although `len(log.handlers)` returns 2 after the first run and 3 after the second run?

- Why is the order of the print and logging commands mixed up?
- And most important:
  How can all the handlers be removed properly? Or the logging forced to start cleanly?

I'm using python 3.7.1 and logging 0.5.1.2

Comment: "Why is the order of the print and logging commands mixed up?" try with `print('text', flush=True)` output from print can be buffered under some circumstances and this forces it to flush

Comment: Yes, this answers the first part, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is more related to your system OS and to your computer hardware characteristics. Everything works fine and prints continuously on my side


About 3 logging entries - maybe there is the same issue with flushing text in the `logging` module


Note: in the part where you remove log handlers, you should make a copy of this list before iterating it. That's why you weren't clearing all logging handlers. Like this:

```
#Remove all handlers:
    for handler in log.handlers[:]: #get rid of existing old handlers
        print('removing handler %s'%handler)
        log.removeHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you remove all handlers:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger()
while logger.hasHandlers():
    logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])
```